# Breaking a data set into chunks with Cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

Does cascading provide a way to break up a dataset into chunks? For example, each chunk would contain 1000000 records, or add up to 1GiB, etc. `Every` + `Buffer` exists, but needs to be preceded by a `GroupBy` that I don't need (I'm also not sure whether it's intended to be used in this way or how exactly to implement it).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Python installed?

```
import pandas as pd
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('C:/your_path_here/main.csv', chunksize=1000000)):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i))
```

or

```
import os
os.getcwd()

csvfile = open('C:/your_path/Book1.csv', 'r').readlines()
filename = 1
for i in range(len(csvfile)):
    if i % 1000000 == 0:
        open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+').writelines(csvfile[i:i+1000000])
        filename += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.5/javadoc/cascading/tap/hadoop/PartitionTap.html and implementing a `Partition` that specifies how to go from a `TupleEntry` to a specific subdirectory.